# Stored procedure that calls a RFID serial number

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have been tasked with creating a stored procedure that calls a RFID serial number out of a table inside a database

[image]

Comment: Is this for SQL Server?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation of sql server and stored proc creation? What have you tried?

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the RFID for a given UPC, your proc should look something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetRFIDForUPC(@UPC NVARCHAR(12)) AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT RFID FROM dbo.RFID_SerialNumbers WHERE UPC = @UPC;
END
```